# How can I manage Cross-platform Apple In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app

my name is Antony Basta and I am the developer of an app called SecuriKey. SecuriKey allows any old apartment building intercom to be controlled from an app. Users can create entry codes that work once, up to a certain date, or are instantly revokable. There is no need for any new or additional hardware – it works with the buildings existing intercom.

Currently, the app is using Stripe for subscriptions and it was initially approved 2 months ago for the App Store. I pushed an update a few weeks ago and Apple Rejected it because I am not using In-App Purchase (IAP). I submit an appeal, mentioning that we offer a consumable service that takes place outside of the app (guideline 3.1.3(e)), it is effectively a "Reader" app since we provide VoIP numbers to our customers (guideline 3.1.3(f)), and SecuriKey requires hardware to function – that is, it will not work without a physical intercom (guideline 3.1.4). Additionally, we do ship physical goods to our customers (NFC tags and Security Signs) monthly and require monthly service personnel to service the building using the physical goods for our own back end workflow. A lot of back and forth has occurred between the review team and at the time of this post, the app is still being reviewed by the board. I thoroughly believe we fit within all of the mentioned IAP exception guidelines – but that's a conversation for another day.

As I wait, I began to delve into using IAP for this product. I was able to jerry-rig the IAP platform to feed Stripe the necessary data through the notifications apple sends when a subscription is made, and I am able to create an account and collect a payment. ***But there's one huge oversight***. This is a cross-platform app. Meaning, roommates or family members who use different mobile operating systems, can be logged into the same account. A user may sign up from the iPhone but his/her roommate/family member may have an android that also has access to the service under the same account. Thus, the android user will not be able to change the IAP subscription plan from the android side of the service. Furthermore, a web-portal is being developed, and using IAP will not allow us to modify the subscription via the web-portal either.

**Has anyone ever dealt with something like this? How can you use IAP for a cross-platform application and allow android users to modify the subscription (Whether it be canceling, upgrading, or downgrading)?**

Comment: Hi Antony, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider editing your question to focus on the technical question you have so that it's easier for people to help you. For example, the first two paragraphs are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If Apple says you have to use IAPs, you should leverage IAPs and not a payment service provider like Stripe.

I'm confused with what

> I was able to jerry-rig the IAP platform to feed Stripe the necessary data through the notifications apple sends when a subscription is made,

means but does not sound like the right thing to do.

> Thus, the android user will not be able to change the IAP subscription plan from the android side of the service. Furthermore, a web-portal is being developed, and using IAP will not allow us to modify the subscription via the web-portal either

Your user will have to use Apple's Platform (i.e. an Apple device that they are signed into) to cancel the IAP subscription.

Comment: Well, the reason why we use Stripe is because the customer management features are so much richer. For one, Stripe lets us see and identify our customers so we can manage them appropriately and have the ability to send them emails – even make a login. Apple doesn't allow this, all subscriptions are theoretically anonymous beyond a receipt ID. No emails, nothing.

Comment: Continually, by using IAP, what will the user do should they decide to switch to android in the future? They'll have the login, but they won't be able to cancel or change their account's subscription package. I wouldn't even be able to help them cancel or change their accounts. Like I've mentioned before, this is a Multiplatform app, meaning multiple users can login to the same account from various devices and manage the account – which is impossible outside of the Apple Ecosystem with IAP.

Answer (score 0):

> How can you use IAP for a cross-platform application and allow android users to modify the subscription (Whether it be canceling, upgrading, or downgrading)

You can't. Take a look at the IAP experience for subscription services like HBO Max. Accounts are all ultimately provisioned through the same system, but the funding source may differ. When you attempt to manage your subscription, the website or android app could inform you that the subscription is billed via Apple, and send you to a page like this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039.

[image: a screenshot of the HBO max subscription management page deferring management to Apple]

If the user has no Apple devices, they can contact Apple Support:

> #### If you don't have an Apple device or Windows PC
>
> - You can cancel Apple Music on the web.
> - You can cancel Apple TV+ on the web.
> - If you want to cancel a different subscription from Apple, contact Apple Support.